# How does Electronic limited Slip differential and Anti lock braking system work together in a car?

Tags: abs, braking, differential, slipping, electronic-stability-control

Does E-Limited slip differential assists the ABS to prevent the wheel locking?

Edit1:Updated the Question from LSD to E-LSD.

Let's take the case where one of the wheels is on an oily road and driver presses the brake pedal to full throttle, Here ABS ensures the wheel doesn't lock and limited-slip differential ensures the wheel on an oily surface doesn't rotate faster by reducing torque supply to it. As both ABS and differential systems are controlling the wheel speeds, there should be some communication between both the ECU's as well. I am not clear how the final speed is decided when both ABS and differential are acted here.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! To my knowledge, the LSD doesn't have much to do with ABS. There are, however, different ABS and LSD's available. You might want to expound on the systems you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

There is generally no relationship between these two.

There is, however, an ABS-related technology that is used on some vehicles these days where the ABS system activates to help with traction.  It does this on non-limited slip vehicles by applying the brakes via the ABS pump to the slipping wheel.

These systems have different names such as "Dynamic Traction Control" etc.